# PHP comparison operator == not working as required. Strange behavior

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, oauth, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to update my user's account once he/she has successfully 
authenticated via Twitter(Twitter Oauth). The callback url is www.xyxy.com/email.php

I want the user to updated his profile and change email id once he/she has been authenticated. 
My `oauth table consists of the following columns:
twitter handle, access_token, access_secret_key, email

The email column is inserted with a garbage value in my INSERT command since I will be updating that 
column in my email.php page. I want the user to see email.php page only if he hasn't updated his 
email id, else he should be landing on the index.php page.

To achieve that, I've used the SELECT command and stored the email field in a variable. Then 
I've compared this variable with the garbage value and accordingly the header() function has been 
written. But the control never seems to enter the if condition.

email.php

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * User has successfully authenticated with Twitter. Access tokens saved to session and DB.
 */

/* Load required lib files. */
session_start();
require_once('twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php');
require_once('config.php');
require('mysqlconnection.php');

/* If access tokens are not available redirect to connect page. */
if (empty($_SESSION['access_token']) || empty($_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token']) || empty($_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token_secret'])) {
    header('Location: ./clearsessions.php');
}
/* Get user access tokens out of the session. */
$access_token = $_SESSION['access_token'];


/* Create a TwitterOauth object with consumer/user tokens. */
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);



/* If method is set change API call made. Test is called by default. */
$data = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');


$screen_name = $data->screen_name;


/*Updating oauth table with user tokens.*/
try {


    // begin the transaction
    $conn->beginTransaction();
    // our SQL statememtns


    $conn->exec("INSERT IGNORE INTO oauth (twitterhandle,access_token, oauth_token_secret, email) 
    VALUES ('".$screen_name."','".$access_token['oauth_token']."','".$access_token['oauth_token_secret']."','inialgarbagevalue@example.com')");


    // commit the transaction
    $conn->commit();
   // echo "New records created successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    // roll back the transaction if something failed
    $conn->rollback();
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT email FROM oauth WHERE twitterhandle = :value");
$stmt->execute(array(':value' => $screen_name));

$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$total = count($result);
//print_r($result);
$email = $result;
print_r($email);


//echo gettype($email[0][0]);
//echo $email[0][0];

$fetchedresult = $email[0]['email'];
$garbagevalue = "inialgarbagevalue@example.com";

//echo $fetchedresult;
```

**Update 1:
   Output of `echo $fetchedresult;`**

inialgarbagevalue@example.com

**Output of `print_r($email);`**

Array ( [0] => Array ( [email] => inialgarbagevalue@example.com ) )

```
 //echo $garbagevalue;

if($fetchedresult == $garbagevalue)
{
echo"if part";

 //take email id from user via a form.
/*
$sql1 = UPDATE oauth   
   SET `emailid` = :newemailid
 WHERE `twitterhandle` = :screen_name
 */
 header('Location: http://www.xyxyxy.com/email.php'); 
}

if($fetchedresult != $garbagevalue)
{
echo "Else part executed";
//header('Location: http://www.xyxyxy.com/index.php'); 
}

$conn = null;

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>XYXY - Index</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>


<body>

<center>
    <div id="content">

     <h3>Account Update</h3>
     <form id="changemail" action="" method="post">
        <p>
          <label for="emailid">Update your account Email ID:</label>
          <input type="text" name="emailid" id="emailid"/>
        </p>


        <p>
          <input type="submit" name="btnUpdate" value="Update" />
        </p>
      </form>

      <td>&nbsp;</td>
<p>
 <?php
    echo "<p align='left'><a href='clearsessions.php' >Sign Out</a></p>";
    ?>
  </p>

        </div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Why am I welcomed with this behavior and how do I achieve the desired scenario?

Comment: You want to fetch an array, not the whole "association". This line's `$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` should be modified.

Comment: But, If I echo $email[0]['email']; I do get the desired output i.e. inialgarbagevalue@example.com. It fails at the if condition after that and echos Else part executed.

Comment: something else is going on in that case this does not match up - you need to follow this guideline:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: *Hm...*, most bizarre.

Comment: However, you've got an echo and a header (with no exit I might add).... that's why. You're outputting before header with `echo"if part";`
 and `header('Location: http://www.xyxyxy.com/email.php');`. You can't do that. Remove/comment out the headers and try it again.

Comment: should be `elseif` not that it would fix this 'error'

Comment: http://ideone.com/AWXWsR raw working demo - ergo the values are not what you think they are

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, and you'll see what I meant by my other comment.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I tried commenting the header. It skips the if loop. I need the header() in my if block. I've used echo for debugging.

Comment: @Dagon Tried an if..else as well. Still the control enters the else part.

Comment: look at the raw demo i posted, now work backwards and echo every variable till you fine the problem

Comment: can you try replacing `$fetchedresult = $email[0]['email'];` with `$fetchedresult = $email['email'];` or `if($fetchedresult == $garbagevalue)` to `if($result == $garbagevalue)` - I'm baffled here. I'd have to go find another piece of PDO-related code to check if data exists from the same row

Comment: @Fred-ii- replaced if($fetchedresult == $garbagevalue) to if($result == $garbagevalue). It still enters the else part and echos Else part executed.
Same is the case with $email['email'];